# Oracle CEP Tools Eclipse plugin - missing requirements

Tags: eclipse, oracle, eclipse-plugin, complex-event-processing

Does anyone have experiences with the "Oracle CEP Tools" plugin for Eclipse? I tried to install it but I get an error due to some missing requirements (see below). Can someone help me? Thanx

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Software being installed: Oracle CEP Tools 11.1.1.20111115-1500 
(com.bea.wlevs.eclipse.tools.feature.feature.group 11.1.1.20111115-1500)

Missing requirement: Oracle CEP Tools 11.1.1.20111115-1500 
(com.bea.wlevs.eclipse.tools.feature.feature.group 11.1.1.20111115-1500) requires 'org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [3.6.0,3.7.0)' 
but it could not be found
```

What is this jdt.feature.group? And where can I find it??
I'm using Eclipse Indigo (recommended by Oracle)

Thanx for Help :)

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group` is the Java Development Tools Feature of Eclipse.

This error is telling you that the feature version must be at least 3.6.0 and less than 3.7.0.

In other words this plugin only works with Eclipse 3.6 (very old).